# Color code WMS maps

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, style

I have various WMS map layers showing state/province capitals and various lower level administration (e.g. district) headquarters.

I want to demarcate the state capitals and district headquarters using colors or something else. By default both are in red.

I am using GeoServer with OpenLayers.

Is this even possible, since I have done some searches, but it results only in stylization of vector layers; not WMS layers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use stylization on server side. I hope [this](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/styling/index.html) tutorial will be hepful.

Comment: precisely the thing i wanted....thx @drnextgis